# Symfony 2.8 Form Button isClicked

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have Symfony in version 2.8.11. I'm creating form with two buttons and I just want to do something like "If button 1 is clicked, redirect to some route, if button 2 is cicked, redirect to another route". In [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/multiple_buttons.html) I found method called isClicked(). The problem is that I can't call such method as it's don't exist ([as seen in attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI4sB.png)). What could be the problem?

**AdminIdType.php**

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Form/AdminIdType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType;

class AdminIdType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('admins', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'AppBundle:Admin', 'choice_label' => 'idAdmina', 'multiple' => true))
            ->add('save', ButtonType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
            ->add('delete', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Delete Post'));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Admin',
        ));

    }
}
```

**AdminController.php**

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Controller/AdminRegistrationController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\AdminType;
use AppBundle\Form\AdminIdType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Admin;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ClickableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("baza/admin/update", name="admin_update")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return type
     */
    public function AdminUpdateAction(Request $request)
    {
        $admin = new Admin();
        $form = $this->createForm(AdminIdType::class, $admin);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // HERE I WANTED TO 
        // if ($form->get('delete')->isClicked) {
        //      do smth
        //   }

        return $this->render(
            'adminUpdate.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `$form->getForm()` in general returns object which implements interface `FormInterface` - and methods of this interface you have in your autocomplete.

But some of this objects can have additional methods, and `\Symfony\Component\Form\SubmitButton` implements `FormInterface` and also `ClickableInterface` with a method `isClicked`

So for your `$form->get('delete')` this method will exist, but for `$form->get('admins')` it will not.

If you want to have an autocomplete, you can cast a method with PHPDoc annotation, which should be supported by your IDE:

```
/** @var $deleteButton \Symfony\Component\Form\SubmitButton */
$deleteButton = $form->get('delete');
$deleteButton->isClicked(); // now you have autocomplete
```

UPD:
And pay your attention:
`if ($form->get('delete')->isClicked())`, not `if ($form->get('delete')->isClicked)`

Comment: Well, the problem is that method `isClicked()` do not exist at all. It is not autocompleted by IDE and if I just type in, I have following error:

`Notice: Undefined property: Symfony\Component\Form\SubmitButton::$isClicked

500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException`

Comment: It's actually working when I do something like this:

`$form = $this->createFormBuilder($admin)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'))
            ->add('saveAndAdd', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save and Add'))
            ->getForm();`

but in **AdminController.php**, instead of **AdminIdType.php**. Still have no autocomplete no matter how I type things in. It's weird.

Comment: Oh, that's the easy one then. See UPD

Comment: Better use `\Symfony\Component\Form\ClickableInterface` than `\Symfony\Component\Form\SubmitButton` directly.

Comment: @Yoshi what do you mean? The type cast on the button? I don't think so, it will not allow to see FormInterface's methods then.

Comment: Ok, yes, if that's required then it's probably better to hint at `SubmitButton`. My reasoning was that, if only the `isClicked()` will be used, then it's better to hint at the interface that actually defines it.